# java selenium driver.getDevTools() is undefined for the type ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium

Can someone tell why I get the following error: getDevTools() is undefined for the type ChromeDriver ?

I want to test network in the chrome browser

```
 import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer;
import net.lightbody.bmp.client.ClientUtil;
import net.lightbody.bmp.core.har.Har;
import net.lightbody.bmp.core.har.HarEntry;
import net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.CaptureType;

import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v96.network.Network;

ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(file)
            .usingAnyFreePort().build();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--incognito");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
    DevTools chromeDevTools = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getDevTools();
    
    chromeDevTools.createSession();
```

Thanks

Comment: This post may be useful for you: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9676

Comment: I am unable to recreate your problem using Selenium 4.1.4 and the chromedriver exe for Chrome version 102. Your code works correctly.

Comment: Why are you typecasting `driver` as `ChromeDriver` if it is already an instance of that type?